# Routing issue in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

i am just new to angular js and when I tried to study routing one error occurs..
please check this..

here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="demoApp">

<head>
    <title>Angular</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div data-ng-view=""> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);
    demoApp.controller('firstController', function($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [{
            name: 'nik',
            city: 'san fransisco'
        }, {
            name: 'henry',
            city: 'new york'
        }, {
            name: 'avida',
            city: 'california'
        }, {
            name: 'lynda',
            city: 'texas'
        }];

        $scope.addCust = function($scope) {
            $scope.customers.push({
                name: $scope.newCust.name,
                city: $scope.newCust.city
            })
        }
    });
    demoApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/view1', {
                controller: 'firstController',
                templateUrl: '1.html'
            })
            .when('/view2', {
                controller: 'firstController',
                templateUrl: '2.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/view1'
            });
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

routing is not working, as it supposed to load "/view2" as default when i take index.html

I hope no need to include code from 1.html and 2.html here, for reference as that just contains the 'li' tag which shows the data from this.

Error is,
angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=demoApp&p1=Error%3A…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A222)

Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must include ng-route script  [angular-route](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.js%22)

Comment: but I see some examples working without adding this.. (following a video tut - in that just these code works!!)

Comment: @GaneshKumarG yeah but what version of angular are you using, and what version is the tutorial using. If you read the error url you have been provided it specifically tells you route is moved to its own module post 1.2, you are using 1.5 ... you need an injection, and in your case because you are using 1.5 you need the script as well.